# How to create a function that converts a Class<T> into Class<U>, where T and U are arbitrary number types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm working with SFML, and I'd like to do things like the following:

```
sf::Texture myTexture;
myTexture.loadFromFile("texture.png");

sf::Sprite mySprite(myTexture);
mySprite.setOrigin(myTexture.getSize() / 2.f); // <~-- error
```

The problem is that `sf::Texture::getSize()` returns a `sf::Vector2<`**`unsigned`**`>`, whilst `sf::Transformable::setOrigin()` expects for a `sf::Vector2<`**`float`**`>`, and they're not convertible into each other.

I thought on creating a function that would accept any `sf::Vector2<T>` and return an equivalent `sf::Vector<U>`, where `T` and `U` are both arbitrary number types, so I could rewrite that last line of code as:

```
// converting from 'unsigned' to 'float'
mySprite.setOrigin(toVector2<unsigned, float>(myTexture.getSize()) / 2.f);
```

What I have so far is the following, but it doesn't work.

```
// Util.h
namespace smi
{
    template <typename FROM, typename TO>
    sf::Vector2<TO> toVector2(const sf::Vector2<FROM> &other)
    {
        return sf::Vector2<TO>(
            static_cast<TO>(other.x),
            static_cast<TO>(other.y));
    }
}

// then ...
mySprite.setOrigin(toVector2<unsigned, float>(myTexture.getSize()) / 2.f);
// ^ no instance of function template "toVector2" matches the argument list
```

Here's an image showing the error:

[image: Error message: no instance of function template "toVector2" matches the argument list]

How could I achieve such a generic conversion?

Comment: Unsigned is not a type. Are you referring to an unsigned int? Also SFML has types for these specific vectors: sf::Vector2i and sf::Vector2f

Comment: A teacher of mine said I could always use just `unsigned` instead of `unsigned int`. But now that you've pointed it out, I tried with `unsigned int`, and the error message is still the same.

Comment: are you sure Util.h is visible at the point of instantiation?  i.e. the file is included and you don't have an inclusion guard in another file that matches the one in Util.h?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will create undefined behaviour because there are many different integer types that can be unsigned. (unsigned char; 8bits, etc..) If you are just going to be using unsigned int & float types, use sf::Vector2f & sf::Vector2u, otherwise the two types you specify must be compatible with eachother in some fashion. If you are storing classes, use dynamic_cast rather than static_cast

Comment: @otc its an unsigned int if 'unsigned' is given without a type to modify.

Comment: @Pete, I have the following inclusion guard: `#pragma once`. Also, I have a `Util.cpp` that includes the `.h` file, as well.

Comment: @otc I don't want to create a function like `sf::Vector2<float> toVector2f(sf::Vector2<unsigned>)`, because there are at least 3 types of `Vector2<T>` at SFML, and I want to be able to convert from/to any combination of them.

Comment: ok, its normal to use #ifndef/#define guards as it is more portable than #pragma once.
Your template looks fine to me except that it should probably be inline.

Comment: try using a local variable to hold the result of myTexture.getSize() and pass that to your function template.

Comment: Who defines the namespace 'smi' this might be being found by ADL or something.  if your template is in the gloabl namespace, prefix it with '::'

Comment: @Pete Still not working. I tried with both local variable and removing `/ 2.f`, but the error is the same.

Comment: @Pete The namespace is mine. I'll add it to the question. My bad.

Comment: The template arguments of toVector2 are around the other way in your error?

Comment: Just change the code to call `toVector2<float>(myTexture.getSize())` and it should work.

Comment: @Pete Yes, they were! I did that before naming them FROM and TO and made a confusion. Also, what Jonathan Wakely said on his answer did work here. I didn't know about argument deduction on templates. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't do this for arbitrary types. There is not necessarily any relationship between two different specializations of a class template, and no generic way to convert from one to the other.

For specific cases you can usually do something like:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
  Thing<To> convert(const Thing<From>& from)
  {
    return Thing<To>( /* internal value(s) of from */ );
  }
```

i.e. construct a new object from the value(s) held in the source object. But to do that you need to know the API of the type, so that you can get the values out and call an appropriate constructor e.g.

```
template <typename To, typename From>
  std::complex<To> convert_complex(const std::complex<From>& from)
  {
    return std::complex<To>( from.real(), from.imag() );
  }
```

or:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
  std::vector<To> convert_vector(const std::vector<From>& from)
  {
    return std::vector<To>( from.begin(), from.end() );
  }
```

or:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
  std::shared_ptr<To> convert_shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<From>& from)
  {
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<To>(from);
  }
```

But there is no way to do that completely generically, as every type has a different API for getting to its internal values (if it's even possible) and for constructing a new object.

Your `toVector2` function looks like it should work though, as it does exactly this. As Pete pointed out, the error shows you have not defined your `toVector2` function as shown in your question: you put the arguments the other way around!

N.B. you can re-order the template parameters so that you can use template argument deduction to simplify your conversion function:

```
template <typename To, typename From>
  sf::Vector2<To> toVector2(const sf::Vector2<From>& other)
  {
    return ...
  }
```

Now you can just call `toVector2<float>(myTexture.getSize())` and the `From` argument will be deduced as `unsigned`.

Since that seems to be how you defined the real function anyway, just change the code to `toVector2<float>(myTexture.getSize())` and it should work.

Comment: Turns out that I was passing the template arguments in the wrong order. Also, I didn't know of this argument deduction. The syntax became even better, as I can now write only the desired type. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for all the additional info. I've just started studying templates.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came up with:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
std::vector<To> transform_vector(const std::vector<From>& input)
{
    std::vector<To> output;
    for (const auto& i : input)
        output.emplace_back(static_cast<To>(i));
    return std::move(output);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> test{ 1.5, 3.8, 2 };
    std::vector<int> conv = transform_vector<double, int>(test);

    for (auto i : conv)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Not sure why compiler can't deduce types.

Comment: Because you put `To` last in the template parameter list. Put `To` first.

Comment: @Barry I learned this today, too. It's a nice feature to know :)